# C++: Passing string arrays to function WITHOUT USING VECTORS

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference, arrays

So for my class assignment I have to do this grade book program.  The part I'm struggling with is figuring out how to pass a string array from one function to another, such that the latter function can perform calculations on the data stored in the string array.  Well, zooming out further to the bigger picture, the string array (which is for student names) is parallel to a double array (which is for scores), and the function receiving the arrays must find highest and lowest, calculate mean, and print output to screen and file.  I get all that last bit, but I can't figure out correct syntax for referring arrays to a function WITHOUT USING VECTORS!

IMPORTANT:  In case you somehow missed it, we are not allowed to use vectors for this assignment.

so the general outline is:

```
//blahblahblah, #includes and other starting things

int myFunc(//prototype-what the heck goes here?)    

int main()
{
    //arrays declared
    string names[MAX_NUM];
    double scores[MAX_NUM];
    //...other stuff main does, including calling myFunc...
}

int myFunc( //header-what the heck goes here?)
{
    //Code here to find highest, lowest, and mean scores from data in scores[]
}
```

Obviously what is in each indicated "what the heck goes here?" location will be related to what's in the other.  But I don't know how to make it all work and every answer I've been able to find just says to use vectors.  Which we haven't covered yet and therefore cannot use...  Help, please?

Comment: what is wrong with vectors?

Comment: What did you try so far? What does your textbook say? What does your C++ programming reference/book/resource say about passing arrays to functions?

Comment: Google "equivalence of pointers and arrays".

Comment: Would something of the form `int myFunc(double (&scores)[MAX_NUM])` be suitable?

Comment: Next question for you guys : how to ask questions WITHOUT SCREAMING IN THE EARS OF PEOPLE. Stay tuned.

Comment: `Which we haven't covered yet and therefore cannot use`  So that implies that you *did* cover passing arrays in your class, right?

Comment: using `std::array` (C++11) has a cleaner syntax than C-array.

Comment: If you haven't covered `std::vector`, then it's too early for you to be worrying about C style arrays.  It sounds like your course is completely broken.

Comment: And for starters, vector or not, you shouldn't be keeping two arrays, just one, with a `struct`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<std::size_t size>
int myFunc(std::string (&names)[size]);

int myFunc(std::string *names, std::size_t numberOfNames);

int myFunc(std::string *names); //implicitly assume names points to MAX_NUM strings
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//blahblahblah, #includes and other starting things

int myFunc(string names[], double scores[], int elementCount);

int main()
{
   //arrays declared
   string names[MAX_NUM];
   double scores[MAX_NUM];
   //...other stuff main does, including calling myFunc...
   myFunc(names, scores, elementCount);
}

int myFunc(string names[], double scores[], int elementCount)
{
   //Code here to find highest, lowest, and mean scores from data in scores[]
}
```

Comment: The size has to be assumed with your solution :-/

Comment: that's easily modified

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use

```
myFunc(std::string* names, double* scores, std::size_t n_students) { /*...*/ }
```

Alternatively, being over-exact with the no-vectors-policy, you could use a `std::list<std::pair<std::string, double>>` or something alike...